# Custom body parameters to twilio create call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am trying to tell twilio to post a custom parameter in the create.call method but its not working.

When twilio creates a call, they make a post request to the [url you provide. (api doc here)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls)

I need to send a `link` in the createCall and cant figure out how to tell twilio to post it.

I have been able to pass this `link` in the actual query like: **myTwimlEndpoint.com?path=`CUSTOMLINK`**

but if `CUSTOMLINK` includes a `?` in it, it **breaks the path**.

How do I post a custom paramater in the twilio create.call?

```
   client.calls.create({ 
        url: 'http://myApp.herokuapp.com/twiml-generator', //?path=' + link,
        to: "RECIEVER_NUM", 
        from: "REG_NUM", // this is my trail number 
        timeout: 12,
        myLink: link// THIS DOESNT POST

      }, function(err, call) { 
        console.log("call made!"); 
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to encode the special characters, like `?`, in your URL component. You can encode the path you're passing using the `encodeURIComponent` function. For example:

```
link = encodeURIComponent('YOUR_LINK_HERE');
client.calls.create({ 
  url: 'http://myApp.herokuapp.com/twiml-generator?path=' + link,
  to: "RECIEVER_NUM", 
  from: "REG_NUM", // this is my trail number 
  timeout: 12
}, function(err, call) { 
  console.log("call made!"); 
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Might be useful to mark this as correct so that others can see that this would work though. Is your Twilio feature all working now then?